# How to create a striped Ext.Dataview

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, senchatouch-2.4

`Ext.dataview.Dataview` unlike `Ext.dataview.List` does not have a `striped` attribute.
Is there a straightforward way of simulating that?

I've tried using `itemTpl` in my `DataView`, but no luck.

```
itemTpl: '<tpl for=".">' + 
             '<div class="{[xindex % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd"]}"></div>' + 
         '</tpl>'
```

Maybe my "for clause" is wrong. Maybe I shouldn't be iterating through the root node...

Comment: So is that ExtJS or Sencha Touch? If ExtJS, which version?

Comment: My mistake - it's Sencha Touch 2.4.1. I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the itemTpl in the DataView the xindex value will be always one. Since it will create the xtemplate for each dataview item.

You can try using the css:

```
dataviewItemCls:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
dataviewItemCls:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

ref :- http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html